# Referencing single value of another column in Power Query Editor

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I would like to get a single value from "table2.MappedValue" for every record in table1 in Power Query Editor,

I have two tables, that have a many to one relationship, table2 is just a mapping table:
table1: ID | Values
table2: ID | MappedValue

when I try Table.Column(#"table2","MappedValue"), I get a list and not a single value.

I can do that from Table tools-> New Column, but I was wondering if that is possible in Power Query Editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by merging queries. In the query editor go to Home tab and select table1 click on merge and merge with table2. Next step is to expand your new column by selecting the dubble arrow in the column and select the column you want.